# Select all where hashtag isn't working

Tags: sql, jdbc, intersystems-cache, dbeaver

I have a column that houses varchar. Some of the data in this column read as a hashtag (no spaces on either side of it, I've checked).

When I do a select * without conditions I can see the hashtag data (in screenshot).

[image]

When I do a select to count the rows with hashtags, I get a return of 0. Why is the query not able to find

Here are my two queries

```
-- returns 0
select count(LastVisitNumber) 
from qcpr_ARF_OC.Visit
where LastVisitNumber = '#';

-- returns several rows and some are just #.
select * from qcpr_ARF_OC.Visit;
```

Comment: Nothing daft like trailing spaces is it?

Comment: Nope, I copied and pasted from a cell to the sql code

Comment: I assume if you use **1167900114** in your `where` clause that the one row is returned? And that it only fails when you try and filter using **#**?

Comment: Just did that and you are correct, when I put in an existing visit number in the where clause, I get a return of 1.

Comment: As a workaround try `NOT LIKE '[0-9]%'`.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work right, so I made it a little longer, and it worked, but didn't return any rows. We only have visit numbers starting with 1, 2, 9.  `where 
LastVisitNumber NOT LIKE '1%' 
and LastVisitNumber NOT LIKE '2%' 
and LastVisitNumber NOT LIKE '9%' 
and LastVisitNumber is NOT NULL;`

Comment: As you say, that you working with Caché. But using some 3rd software for sql. I think you should check it Caché side, in System ManagementPortal

Comment: Thanks, I tried it in the web application native to the Inter-systems Cache system and it returned the same 0 result.

Comment: Looks to me like a display overflow...  Try enlarging that column of which you took a screenshot.

Comment: @TallTed I know it's a # we use that character on purpose in our workflow. Good idea though.

Comment: I meant, not to try count hashtags, I wanted, that you should execute query which returns hashtags. And I think you should also check indexes, and reindex this table.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if the hash requires an escape, even though Caché documentation doesn't seem to say anything about it...

```
where LastVisitNumber like '%\#%';
```

If that fails, these 4 alternative queries may help....  Just swap out the `ORDER BY` clauses.

```
    SELECT LastVisitNumber, 
           CHAR_LENGTH(LastVisitNumber)
      FROM qcpr_ARF_OC.Visit
     WHERE LastVisitNumber NOT NULL
  ORDER BY LastVisitNumber
# ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(LastVisitNumber)
# ORDER BY LastVisitNumber DESC
# ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(LastVisitNumber) DESC
```

You might also try querying through ODBC (instead of JDBC), which makes it easier to generate traces that may reveal surprising details.

Comment: A great idea. I tried the escape, but it didn't work. I have tried the query right in the Cache data tool and it provides the same 0 result. My mind is blown. I've picked up the results I needed using a similar order method, but I still want to get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably other characters that you cannot see.  I would start with:

```
select count(LastVisitNumber) 
from qcpr_ARF_OC.Visit
where LastVisitNumber like '%#%';
```

This assumes that `LastVisitNumber` is actually a string, despite its name.

Comment: I've tried that, still 0 results returned. Yes, I checked the table properties, it's a varchar, not an int column.